# How to add RSS Icon/link as a widget?

Tags: rss, icon

When I search plug-ins for RSS, so many of them are dealing with pulling in RSS feeds.  I just want an RSS icon to let people subscribe to my feed?  I'm also using FeedBurner.  I looked for Feedburner plugins as well, but still confused what is simple and best.

Shouldn't all blogs have an RSS icon? Or is that simply a matter of the theme? Seems like the default 2010 theme would even have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is matter of theme, unlike technical links for browser discovery (that make RSS show up in browser address bar) there is no convention on how to present RSS links in page. So that completely up to designer/web master.

The simplest way is putting together HTML for link (or taking FeedBurner's snippet) and putting it into text widget.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rarst's answer above, I put this in my text box:

```
<a href="?feed=rss2">RSS Feed/Feedburner <img src="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/lib/images/icons/feed-icon-12x12-orange.gif"></a>
```

And even grabbing the icon from the feedburner.google.com site.